# Facebook API Android

Tags: android, feed

I was trying to create a feed app which will show the feeds from facebook and other social platforms but the problem I was facing was the  real time update on my server when a user post something on his wall in facebook. Is there any way that I can get real time data without making any requests to facebook servers to see if the user has posted anything i.e. the facebook servers will notify me that the user has added a post so I can fetch that post and save to my server and notify others that the user has added a post on facebook.

P.S.- I have read about Webhooks from graph Api but was not sure whether they will work or not

Comment: I'm also working on a Android project with Webhooks.. For me, it took quite a long time before I understood how Webhooks are working, but the setup of Facebook Webhooks is quite easy...
One thing you should remember: Facebook notifies you when there is an update, it shows what kind of update (event, post, page...) but it does not show the exact update... For example: Facebook notifies you that there is an event update, then you need to update all the events !! Because Facebook doesn't tell you which event has been updated... I know, this is sad :( If you have more questions, SHOOT !

Comment: thanks nick I will try it

Comment: If you find a better solution than updating all the events, please let me know, I'm also interested in this.. but I don't think it's possible with the current Facebook API

Comment: @NickSpriet, you always have to go through the Facebook API for updating the data, that's what the doc says.

Comment: @verybadalloc: yes that's true, but you always need to update everything because the webhook doesn't tell you which item has been updated.. it only tells for example that there is an update for your events.. but you do not know which event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, webhooks are the way to go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5
Your callback URL will receive a POST, and will need to return a 200.

**New in 2.5+**: your callback URL will also need to be on HTTPS.

According to the doc, if you subscribe to a change in the field `feed`, you will be notified, at which point you would have to make a query to get all posts.

They even have sample setup for parse and heroku: https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples

NOTE: your app will need to be whitelisted by Facebook. Also, a user can disable this behavior in their app settings.